# Why is this following integral not zero ?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am given the integral 
$$\int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx$$ i know that the answer should be $2\pi$ however, $f(x) = \sqrt{4-x^2}$ is an even function and so it should give zero since $f(x) = f(-x)$ but why is it not the case here ? any suggestions

Comment: This is not the case for even functions. You're talking about odd functions.

Comment: Odd functions are zero when integrated centered on the y axis.  Whatever is positive on one side is negative on the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you *Integrator* for that geometric demonstration. 
Algebraically though, we know even functions have the property $f(x) = f(-x)$ so: $$\int_{-a}^a {f(x)}\,dx = \int_{-a}^0 {f(x)}\,dx + \int_0^a {f(x)}\,dx $$ but noting that the first component of that sum can be expressed as:$$\int_{-a}^0 {f(-x)}\,dx$$ we then use $u=-x,\, du = -dx$ and change the limits accordingly ($0\to0,\,-a\to a$) to get:$$\int_{-a}^a {f(x)}\,dx = -\int_a^0 {f(u)}\,du + \int_0^a {f(x)}\,dx $$ which equates to: $$\int_0^a {f(x)}\,dx + \int_0^a {f(x)}\,dx =2\,\int_0^a{f(x)}\,dx.$$ So really, the definite integral you are trying to evaluate should equate to ***twice*** the region in the first or second quadrant bounded by the graph and the two axes.
*Ross Millikan* demonstrates the other case, the zero integral for an odd function.

Answer (score 3):

Even functions (like this one) over an interval symmetric around zero can give nonzero answers.  It is odd functions that integrate to zero over an interval symmetric around zero.  If $f(x)=-f(-x)$, then $\int_{-a}^af(x)\ dx=\int_{-a}^0f(x)\ dx+\int_{0}^af(x)\ dx=-\int_{0}^af(x)\ dx+\int_{0}^af(x)\ dx=0$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the area is to consider rewritten $y = \sqrt{4 - x^{2}}$ as

$x^{2} + y^{2} = 4$. This is obtained by squaring both sides $y = \sqrt{4 - x^{2}}$.

Then if you notice,   the graph of  $y = \sqrt{4 - x^{2}}$ represents a semicircle centered at the origin with radius $2$. 
Hence the integral represents the area of a semicircle. Then in general the area of a semicircle is $A = \frac{\pi(r^{2})}{2}$.

Then $\int_{-2}^{2} y = \sqrt{4 - x^{2}} =  \frac{\pi(2)^{2}}{2} = 2\pi$

In general

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[-a, a]$.

$(i)$ if $f$ is even $[f(-x) = f(x)]$, then $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx $.

$(ii)$ if $f$ is odd  $[f(-x) = -f(x)]$, then $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx = 0$.

Then you can verify $y = \sqrt{4 - x^{2}}$ is not an odd function. Thus its integral cannot be equal to zero.